It is possible to launch another app after a device reboot without using SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
I'm trying to launch an app when the device restarts using a BroadcastReceiver. I've successfully achieved that. However, the issue lies in the requirement of SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW to make this happen. If the user lacks SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission (for instance, Amazon FireStick FireOS doesn't have this permission built into the system), it poses a challenge. The app can't launch after restart, I've manually enable the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW using ADB command :
adb shell appops set a.b.c SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow
The code :
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String pkgName = SPUtils.getInstance().getString("selectedAppToLaunch", "nothing");
            if (!pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase("nothing")) {
                if (AppUtils.isAppInstalled(pkgName)) {
                    openAppAutomatically(pkgName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void openAppAutomatically(String pkgName) {
        AppUtils.launchApp(pkgName);
    }
}

It's possible to make the broadcast launch the app without using SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission ?

Unfortunately no there is no way to get it to work in FireOS without using ADB
